# Display:none or visibility:hidden on body element on page load - does it affect SEO?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, seo

I am building a web page and I do some JS calculations and styling to make  fancy things. However, I am stuck with [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). First I call the required styles, then depending on JS calculations I change some paddings and margins on divs. This leads to some kind of flashing of the page. To ommit this, I want to set `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` to the `body` element until the calculations are done, then show the page.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <!-- These meta tags come first. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap Theme Example</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="assets/js/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('body').hide();
        // ... do calculations and styling ...
        $('body').show();
    </script>
</head>
```

Do this affect SEO? Any other ways of getting around that problem?

Comment: I'd say it most certainly affects SEO, Google is always looking for ways to figure out if content is hidden or not, as it used to be a common way to manipulate SERPS -> https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=en

Comment: How about just setting `opacity: 0` to the body, then restoring to `opacity: 1`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not hiding keywords or spamming with content there should be no issue.

For more you can check this topic on [Google Webmaster Central](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/webmasters/crawling-indexing--ranking/9IJHC83yge8) forum:

> "Merely using display:none will not automatically trigger a penalty.
>   The key is whether or not there is a mechanism - either automatic or
>   one that is invoked by the user - to make the content visible.Google
>   is becoming very adept at processing JavaScript to find and interpret
>   such mechanisms.If you use valid HTML, CSS, and JavaScript you have
>   nothing to worry about. Good luck!"

Hope this helps.